# Shifting Characters and Making Them Meaningful Words

Tags: java

Note: This is homework; please don't write the code, just provide guidance.

The problem: There is a complicated text, and we have a given dictionary structure.

I need to make text meaningful using the given dictionary structure.

Possible meanings of these words can be written in the dictionary. (For example: `opeh` -> `hope`) We can only use `.charAt`, `.length`, and `.equals`.

I know I need to shift characters to the left or right, but I don't know how.

Edit: I'll give an example to make the question clear.

```
String complicated = "omT htboug a rca terdayyes"
String dictionary = "a bought car Tom yesterday"
```

The dictionary contains only the words in the text.

```
Output: Tom bought a car yesterday
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far, and point out what's not working so we can help you figure out where you might be going wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what the specific problem is. What is this "dictionary structure"? If it's a hash of words => translations you shouldn't need to do any manual shifting; it's a lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague :

- Is it just mistyping ?
- Can there be additional letters in a word ?
- Can there be missing letters in a word ?

I'm not even sur it should be on this stack exchange !

Based on what you've told us, i'll assume you do keep exactly the same length and same letters even if you mistype, just in a different order.

Anyway here is how I'd do it (pseudo-code) :

```
For (each word in text) {
if(isCorrect(word)){    // Check if it exists in your table
  next;     //  Move on to the next word
}
 else {// You need to decide with which word you need to replace it to correct it
      findBestMatch(word);     
     }
}

 findBestMatchWord(word) { // To do so first you can decide that you're only looking for words in your table  that have the same length 
 filterTableByLength(word.length())
 for (each entry in table) { // Then you need to decide on how you choose the right word:
    calculateMatchScore(entry) 
    /* To do so, you'll need some kind of scoring system
     You can look for how close the mistyped word with swapped letters is close to each word in your table using charAt().*/
 }
return bestEntryMatch; //    Once you've found the best match, just replace the word and move to the next one.
}
```

Edit: Just one way of doing it, try to detail your question as much as possible next time;

Comment: However, I assumed you can have many words in your dictionnary that have exactly the same length and exactly same letters in different orders, it might not be the case, and it makes everything easier, you don't need any scoring then. A simple lookUp in the table using some sort() and contains() to check if an entry has all the letters will be sufficient.
On the other hand, some words such as "on" and "no", wouldn't be detected as mistyping in the solution i drafted, as you're not checking the gramatical or syntaxical sense of the sentence, and that would make the exercice way more difficult.

Comment: I can't use sort() or contains(). These are forbidden

Comment: @Ari I see you edited your question :)
It seems like my assumptions were correct, so my answer still works, you can use the approach in the pseudo code. Is it clear enough for you ?
It's even easier because as soon as you find a letter in the word of the dictionnary that is different from a letter in the mistyped word, you know it's not the right word and you can check the next one right away.